# An exercise on Linear algebra in PDE

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I'm struggling to show some exercise given in the PDE book of Krylov(Lecture s on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Spaces.

> **Exercise 1.4.7.** Let $A=(a^{ij})$ and $U=(u_{ij})$  be $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices. Assume that 
>   $$ \mu |\xi|^2 \leq \xi^T A \xi \le \nu |\xi|^2$$ 
>   for all  $\xi \in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mu,\nu>0$ are some constants. Prove that 
>   $$ \frac{1}{2\mu^2} \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^2 a^{ij} u_{ij}\right)^2 \geq \frac{\mu^2}{2\nu^2} \left (\sum_{i,j=1}^2 u^2_{ij} \right)+\det U.$$

Answer (score 1):

Today I found a proof of this problem. The proof is quite messy.

Note that since $A,U$ are symmetric, we have 
$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{2}a^{ij}u_{ij}.
$$
Since $A$ and $U$ are symmetric matrix, we can diagonalize these,
say 
$$
A=P\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix}P^{T},\quad U=Q\begin{bmatrix}\varepsilon_{1} & 0\\
0 & \varepsilon_{2}
\end{bmatrix}Q^{T},
$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal matrix. We may assume that $\lambda_{1}\ge\lambda_{2}$
and $\varepsilon_{1}\ge\varepsilon_{2}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right) & =\mathrm{tr}\left(P\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix}P^{T}Q\begin{bmatrix}\varepsilon_{1} & 0\\
0 & \varepsilon_{2}
\end{bmatrix}Q^{T}\right)\\
 & =\mathrm{tr}\left(Q^{T}P\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix}P^{T}Q\begin{bmatrix}\varepsilon_{1} & 0\\
0 & \varepsilon_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align*}
Since $P,Q$ are orthogonal matrix, $P^{T}Q$ are also orthogonal
matrix. Let us denote this $R=P^{T}Q$. Write 
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a^{2}+c^{2}=1$ and $b^{2}+d^{2}=1$, $a^{2}+b^{2}=1$, $c^{2}+d^{2}=1$.
Then this implies $a^{2}=d^{2}$ and $b^{2}=c^{2}$. So 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right) & =a^{2}\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+b^{2}\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{2}+c^{2}\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{1}+d^{2}\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\\
 & =a^{2}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\right)+b^{2}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{2}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{1}\right).
\end{align*}

Note 
$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2}=a^{4}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\right)^{2}+2a^{2}b^{2}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{2}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{1}\right)+b^{4}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{2}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{1}\right)^{2}
$$

We split three cases

- (i) $\varepsilon_{1}\ge\varepsilon_{2}\ge0$
- (ii) $0\ge\varepsilon_{1}\ge\varepsilon_{2}$
- (iii) $\varepsilon_{1}\ge0\ge\varepsilon_{2}$

These are all tedious calculations:

(i) Note that 
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2} & \ge\mu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2} & \ge\mu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right).
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2} & \ge\mu^{2}\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right)^{2}\left[a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}+b^{4}\right]\\
 & =\mu^{2}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+2\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
 & \ge\mu^{2}\left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+2\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right).
\end{align*}

(ii) Note that 
\begin{align*}
0\ge\mu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right) & \ge\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\ge\nu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
0\ge\mu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right) & \ge\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\ge\nu\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right).
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2} & \ge\mu^{2}\left(\varepsilon_{1}+\varepsilon_{2}\right)^{2}\left[a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}+b^{4}\right]\\
 & =\mu^{2}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+2\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
 & \ge\mu^{2}\left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+2\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right).
\end{align*}

(iii) Note that 
$$
\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{1}\le\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)\le\nu\varepsilon_{1}+\mu\varepsilon_{2}.
$$
So we must divide three cases.

(1) $\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)=0$. Since $\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{1}\le0\le\mu\varepsilon_{2}+\nu\varepsilon_{1}$,
we have 
$$
\left(\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{2}\right)\left(\mu\varepsilon_{2}+\nu\varepsilon_{1}\right)\le0.
$$
Rewrite this inequality. Then 
$$
\mu\nu\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+\left(\mu^{2}+\nu^{2}\right)\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\le0.
$$
So 
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2} & \le-\frac{\mu\nu}{\mu^{2}+\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)\\
 & =-\frac{1}{\frac{\mu}{\nu}+\frac{\nu}{\mu}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)\\
 & \le-\frac{1}{2\frac{\nu^{2}}{\mu^{2}}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
 & =-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right).
\end{align*}
Hence 
$$
\frac{\mu^{2}}{\nu^{2}}\left(\mu^{2}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+2\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\le0\le\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2},
$$
that is, 
$$
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2}\ge\frac{\mu^{4}}{\nu^{2}}\mathrm{tr}\left(U^{2}\right)+2\det\left(U\right).
$$

(2) Assume $\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)\neq0$ and $\left|\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{1}\right|\le\left|\nu\varepsilon_{1}+\mu\varepsilon_{2}\right|$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\mu^{2}}\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2} & \ge\frac{1}{2\mu^{2}}\left(\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{1}\right)^{2}\\
 & \ge\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+2\mu\nu\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
 & \ge\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}\right)+\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}.
\end{align*}

Note that 
$$
\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}\right)\ge\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right).
$$
So in this case, we obtain the desired inequality.

(3) Assume $\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)\neq0$ and $\left|\nu\varepsilon_{2}+\mu\varepsilon_{1}\right|>\left|\nu\varepsilon_{1}+\mu\varepsilon_{2}\right|$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\mu^{2}}\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2} & \ge\frac{1}{2\mu^{2}}\left(\nu\varepsilon_{1}+\mu\varepsilon_{2}\right)^{2}\\
 & \ge\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}+2\mu\nu\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}.
\end{align*}

Note that 
$$
\frac{1}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\nu^{2}\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\mu^{2}\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)\ge\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right).
$$

So in this case, we obtain the desired inequality.

By all these three cases, we obtain the following inequality:

$$
\left[a^{2}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{1}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{2}\right)+b^{2}\left(\lambda_{1}\varepsilon_{2}+\lambda_{2}\varepsilon_{1}\right)\right]^{2}\ge\mu^{2}\left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\nu^{2}}\left(\varepsilon_{1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{2}^{2}\right)+2\varepsilon_{1}\varepsilon_{2}\right).
$$
That is, 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)^{2} & \ge\mu^{2}\left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\nu^{2}}\mathrm{tr}\left(U^{2}\right)+2\det U\right)\\
 & =\frac{\mu^{4}}{\nu^{2}}\mathrm{tr}\left(U^{2}\right)+2\mu^{2}\det U.
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
$$\frac{1}{2\mu^{2}}\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{2}a^{ij}u_{ij}\right)^{2}\ge\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\nu^{2}}\sum_{i,j=1}^{2}u_{ij}^{2}+\det U.$$
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use $\mathrm{tr}(AU)=\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^2 a^{ij} u_{ij}\right)$. You may have found this in the hints to the exercises at the end of the chapter,  note that in the hint for this exercise, it is also given that the trace is invariant under orthogonal transformation. The first orthogonal transformation associated with symmetric matrices is the one that is associated with the diagonalisation of the matrix.

I'll not give away everything, but these steps should guide you to the answer:

1) Write $A$ as $A = P^T D P$.

2) Observe that $\mathrm{tr}(AU) = \mathrm{tr}(PAP^T P U P^T) = \mathrm{tr}(DPUP^T)$.

3) Make an estimate for $\mathrm{tr}(DP U P^T)$ by estimating the eigenvalues of $A$ (and thus the elements of $D$).

4) Now transform $U$ back using $P$ again. You should now have $\mathrm{tr}(AU) \geq \mu  \mathrm{tr}(U)$.

5) Use the diagonalization of $U$ to get the sum of the eigenvalues as the trace.

6) Now square on both sides and write out using the transformation of $U$ again you can show that the expression you on the right hand side of your squared inequality equals $\sum_{i,j=1}^2 u^2_{ij} +2 \det U$.

7) Now you can obtain the desired inequality by dividing by 2 and using $\frac{\mu}{\nu} \leq 1$.

I hope this helps you, if you have any questions about the details, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the statement (4) is not generally true. 

Take
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\mu & 0\\
0 & \nu
\end{bmatrix},\quad U=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\
1 & -6
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then these satisfy all condition in the assumption. Note 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right) & =\mu-6\nu,\\
\mathrm{tr}\left(U\right) & =-5.
\end{align*}
From $\mu\le\nu$, we have 
$$6\nu\ge6\mu.$$
So by observing $\mu\mathrm{tr}\left(U\right)=-5\mu$ and $\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right)=\mu-6\nu$,
$$\mu\mathrm{tr}\left(U\right)\ge\mathrm{tr}\left(AU\right).$$

Comment: @WillKwon You are right indeed. I think the answer can be fixed by taking the square of the trace from the start, but it will take some more calculations and maybe the cases in which the product of the diagonals of $U$ is either positive of negative should be split up. I will try to fix the answer when I have the time for it.